# who uses ~/.wget-hsts file except wget or which software starts wget from inside?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

I didn't use wget for a long time, but some days ago I've found, someone modified ~/.wget-hsts in the last hour.
Have you got any idea, which linux (ubuntu 16.04) software starts wget without any signs of starting it?
Nowadays I use python3's pip, ubuntu's snap which can download something from the net, and opera, chromium - these installed as snap package. I've tried to run them (to download something), but they don't use wget for download.
I'm clueless... :(

Comment: `apt-cache --installed rdepends wget` will show you packages installed in your Ubuntu that depend on `wget`. Snaps are different story, I think.

Comment: Thanks. 
In that list I found nothing interesting. (except rkhunter) :(  But you're right, if it was a legal action, then it could be caused by one of them... I fear, someone got into my LAN... :(

Answer (score 1):

O.K., I've found the source of that...
The rkhunter --update starts (sometimes???) a wget (using execve system call)), to download data file updates.